# pipenv not installing pinned version of Django in Pipfile

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, pipenv

I am building a Docker container from a Python application. The version of Python is `3.6.9` thus I am using `FROM python:3.6.9-slim-stretch`. In the Pipfile I am pinning the version of Django at `Django = "==2.1.10"`.

The Dockerfile build steps are:

```
...
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv gunicorn

RUN mkdir -p /var/myapp
WORKDIR /var/myapp
COPY . .
RUN pipenv lock
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy
RUN rm -rf /root/.local/share/virtualenvs

RUN python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

When it prints the version of Django however instead of using the pinned version in the Pipfile `2.1.10` it is using `2.2.4`. How do I get pipenv install to use the version in my Pipfile `2.1.10`?

Comment: try `pipenv run python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"`.

Comment: You seem to be creating/installing a vitualenv and then proceed to delete it... (I think `/root/.local/share/virtualenvs` is the default location for pipenv created virtualenvs.

Comment: All the guides I have seen say this is the correct approach since in a Docker container you don't want a virtualenv. Thus why I am doing `pipenv install --system --deploy`

Comment: I see, didn't notice the `--system` flag.  Can you share your `Pipfile`?

Comment: offtopic: you don't need virtualenvs in docker. You can safely install from requirements.txt container give you isolation

Comment: try with remove of line
'RUN rm -rf /root/.local/share/virtualenvs'